# Firebase dynamic link (console created) support custom query parameters using ActionCodeSettings and Password Reset?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

Is there a way to pass custom query parameters in Firebase Dynamic Links that are created using the console?

My workflow is as follows:

1. Reset Password screen that takes email and executes `sendPasswordResetEmail(email, settings)`
2. Go to email and select link which opens app to screen to reset password: https://xxxxx.page.link?link=https://xxxx-00000.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey%3DAIzaSyDxTJUhYNwbMpoRhRWde74tAqV0CMKHh_o%26mode%3DresetPassword%26oobCode%3DccgIWg7D-FPtRTp2OXon8UaIB1AL0_qpktnAL--P-eMAAAFsgjDmkw%26continueUrl%3Dhttps://example.com/%26lang%3Den&apn=com.example&amv
3. App is launched and we go to the screen to enter a new password.
4. Call `FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(getIntent())`
5. Use `pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink().getQueryParameter("oobCode"));` to get query parameters from the dynamic link (in this case get our password code that we use to reset the password.
6. Use oobCode in previous step and call `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().confirmPasswordReset(actionCode, password)` on button click (grabbing password from use inputted editText field) to reset password.

Ideally I would like to login my user after the password reset.  In order to do this I need to have the email address used in the password reset (I need to get firestore document information from the user trying to login).

So I need to be able to pass the email address to the screen to reset the password.

Here are my relevant code snippets:

Initial "Forgot password screen": User enters email here.
First build my action code settings, then execute the sendPasswordResetEmail() method.

```
String url = "https://example.com"; //my deep link set in Firebase console
        ActionCodeSettings settings = ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
                .setAndroidPackageName(
                        getPackageName(),
                        true, /* install if not available? */
                        null   /* minimum app version */)
                .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
                .setUrl(url)
                .build();

 mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email, settings)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
                        }
                        else {
                            Exception e = task.getException();
                            Log.w(TAG, "passwordResetRequest:failure " + e.getMessage(), task.getException());
                            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Then after selecting link in email we go to the reset password screen.
in here we call the following to get parameters from the dynamic link:

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
                .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                        // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                        Uri deepLink = null;
                        if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null && pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink() != null) {
                            deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                            actionCode = deepLink.getQueryParameter("oobCode");
                            actionMode = deepLink.getQueryParameter("mode");
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                    }
                });
```

Finally we use the oobCode (action code to permit a password reset), and on button click and user input for a new password, we reset the password using:

```
resetPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (actionCode != null && !actionCode.equals(""))
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().confirmPasswordReset(actionCode, newPassword.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null)
                            Log.d(TAG, "Deep Link confirmPassReset: " + task.getResult().toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Here's where I'm struggling.  I'm trying to pass an email address when building the `ActionCodeSettings`.  For example:
`String url = "https://example.com/?email=jsmith@gmail.com";`  And then try to get them in the reset password screen using:
`deepLink.getQueryParameter("email");`
But everytime I try this I keep getting `null`.  What am I missing.  Is it even possible to pass custom query parameters with a dynamic link that was created in the Firebase console?  If not, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need get the link first

```
val actionUrl = deepLink.getQueryParameter("continueUrl")
```

And get the email value with subString

```
actionUrl.substring(actionURL.lastIndexOf("=") + 1, actionURL.length)
```